# c:\QA\New Text Document.txt - file(s) not in client view. "Perforce Server" Error

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

While trying to Add file from workspace to the Pending tab, it shows me the following error:

c:\QA\New Text Document.txt - file(s) not in client view.

In dashboard the message is:

Helix P4V is having trouble translating the location "c:\QA" to a valid workspace location. To filter using this location, drag the folder from the workspace tree to the workspace folder field or include the depot location in your workspace view.

Workspace name is: QA
Workspace root: C:\QA

Using depot: rr which having Client Expression: //QA/rr/...

Depot path is : //rr

Could you please help in resolving this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change the client view from:

```
//rr/... //QA/rr/...
```

to:

```
//rr/... //QA/...
```

and the file you're trying to add will map to the `//rr` depot.

Comment: Also I am facing another issue while  dragging the whole folder to pending  window and trying to SUBMIT IT.
The error I am getting is : Operation 'mkdir' failed.

could someone please help on this.

Comment: Without seeing the whole error message it's hard to say, but just as a wild guess, might be a problem with the server filesystem?  Forward the error message to your Perforce server admin and see if they can help.

Comment: The error is: Operation 'mkdir' failed.
Librarian checkin //src_flashbackplayer/flashbackplayer/default.aspx failed.
RCS can't make directory for //src_flashbackplayer/flashbackplayer/default.aspx,v!
mkdir: //src_flashbackplayer/flashbackplayer/: The network path was not found.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like your depot is configured wrong (like the admin didn't understand that the `Map` is supposed to be a path on the server filesystem, or they tried to point it to a network drive that's not available).  Talk to the admin!